# Weird output when converting from string to const char* in c++

Tags: c++

Consider the MWE below,

```
std::string return_string() 
{
    return "this is a string"
}
int main()
{
    const char *y = return_string().c_str();
    std::string str = return_string();
    const char *x = str.c_str();

    std::cout << return_string() << std::endl; //Prints "this is a string"
    std::cout << y << std::endl;  // Prints Weird characters
    std::cout << x << std::endl;  //Prints "this is a string"

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a function which returns a string and I need to convert it to a c-style string. Doing `return_string().c_str()` gives me weird output like
`▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌p`. But if I store the output of a function in a string first and then convert that string to a c-style string it works. What is wrong with the first way?

Comment: The string returned in `return_string` is a temporary. A pointer (like `char*`) will not preserve the lifetime of that temporary.

Comment: As an aside, it appears today is a slow day. Everyone is racing to write their own answer to a question that has been asked a dozen times.

Comment: How is that a MWE? It doesn't even compile.

Comment: Really it compiles for me on visual studio. Sorry about the duplicate, it's hard to search for answers without the familiarity of the terms used.

Comment: @voidlife: No worries on your part. The answerers know better.

Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27627413) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35980664) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19244331) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6456359) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2657178) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10006891) [7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15449544) [8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22330250) [9](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3733582) [10](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24488122) [11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33659609) [12](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35993690) There's more, too

Comment: Duplicates round two: [13](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23464504) [14](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41240590) [15](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11368483) [16](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14820008) [17](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40553758) [18](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14748860) [19](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20883180) [20](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12323049) [21](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14533540) [22](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23016688) [23](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23869552) [24](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25380253)

Comment: Duplicates round three [25](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26304239) [26](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18044605) [27](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31690826) [28](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39006506) [29](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2833682) [30](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34873395) [31](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35425068) [32](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4564540) [33](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5947129) [34](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27256277) [35](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25658553) [36](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13474486) [37](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4804154)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `return_string().c_str()` you get the pointer to a temporary object that will go out of scope once the expression is finished. If you save the pointer and use it later you will have *undefined behavior*.

With

```
std::string str = return_string();
```

you *copy* the returned temporary object. Getting a pointer to the copy will work since it still exists in the program at the point when you use the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *y = return_string().c_str();
```

is a problem if you wish to use `y` later to access the contents. In that line, the return value of `return_string()` is a temporary that gets destroyed after that line is executed. Hence, `y` is dangling pointer.

Accessing the contents of a dangling pointer causes undefined behavior.

When you use

```
std::string str = return_string();
const char *x = str.c_str();
```

`x` is not a dangling pointer as long as `str` is in scope. Hence,

```
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

is well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "convert from `string` to `const char*`". No such thing exists, because a const char* does not contain characters. It is not a string! It only pointers to some characters somewhere.

In this case, via `std::string::c_str()`, it points to characters that no longer exist.